# Full screen creates jerk in next activity (Some devices only behaves like that: moto, nexus and one plus etc)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop, appcompatactivity

I am trying to show splash screen as full screen. It is working but next activity display with jerk. (second activity also come as a full screen and then try to fit the notification bar. It is looks like a jerk)

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

OR I tried with this code also but I am getting same problem

```
      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

and in the second activity I was tried with this code also. but no luck.

```
 getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

I tried with xml based code also. but no luck

```
<style name="Theme.MyFullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

**Full screen is achieved but next activity displayed with jerk.**

Answer (score 1):

A lot of reasons could cause screen jerk in Android. Simply reading your code doesn’t help solve the problem. I would list out some potential solutions but the most efficient way is still debugging by yourself.

**The first potential solution** is to apply

```
getWindow().addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

This flag will make the Window Rect size being *(-10000, -10000 - 10000, 10000)*. Most likely, it could affect the measurement while we’re inflating the view. But be careful, applying FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS could break logics depending on regular window size. If you want to  add other components on this full-screen view, you should think twice.

Another potential reason which could cause this problem is that, you are using `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility()` and `getWindow().setFlags()` at the same time. According to [the Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html),  when it comes to hiding status bar and showing fullscreen, they are actually targeting different versions. Therefore, **second potential solution** is try not to use the two sets of APIs in your activities at the same time.

**Debug Tooltips:**

Following is one real case I encountered and my debug process.

While android is doing a full-screen transition, the view will keep drawing itself. The logic mainly happens inside `ViewRootImpl.java`. Go checkout the following calls and set breakpoint to see whether you can find something interesting.

1. The start point to look at is draw().
2. Then scrollToRectOrFocus() call inside draw()
3. In scrollToRectOrFocus(), there is
   `if (scrollY != mScrollY) {… mScroller = new Scroller(mView.getContext()); …}`
4. back in draw(),
   `boolean animating = mScroller != null && mScroller.computeScrollOffset();`
   tells us if the scroller has been initialized, we should animate the current view. So the initialization of a scroller is the root cause of the layout jerk.

After tracking down the code, I found out that during animation the update of mPendingVisibleInsetsand mPendingContentInsets inside ViewRootImpl.java is inconsistent. And by applying solution #2 I mentioned above, I solved that bug.